# Detect a copy operation with Inotify

Tags: linux, ubuntu, copy, inotify, ext4

I'm testing Inotify on ext4 no ubuntu 14.04 and when performing copy or creation operation I get the same following Inotify events:

cp file newfile

IN_CREATE  newfile
IN_MODIFY  newfile
IN_CLOSE   newfile

echo "foo" >> newfile

IN_CREATE  newfile
IN_MODIFY  newfile
IN_CLOSE   newfile

Is there any possibility to distinguish this two situations?
I would like to have information that a copy was performed and what was source and destination file.
If there is no possibility to do it by Inotify, can it be done by any other way?

Thank You for Your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "copy" in Unix. Even the most advanced syscalls for copying files (sendfile and copy_file_range) ultimately boil down to duplicating data between two independent files, using an intermediate buffer.

---

But you can use some guessing to identify file copies with decent degree of certainty.

Suppose, that

1. Two files are open: A and B (without specific order)
2. A is read from (IN_ACCESS)
3. B is written to (IN_MODIFY)
4. A and B are closed
5. A was open for reading (as identified by IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)
6. B was open for writing (as identified by IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
7. A and and B have same data size (stat.st_size) afterwards

Note, that the sequence above is just common heuristic, not strict rule. There may be other events with not-so-obvious order (for example truncating or fallocating target file—IN_MODIFY—prior to opening source file). The copying process might unlink existing target file and create new file specifically for copying, in which case that new file must be *timely* subjected to observation with inotify (!!). You might miss some (or all) events because of subscription races, which are completely undetectable by design.

You might also massively miss events because of inotify queue overflows (IN_Q_OVERFLOW).

Inotify can not detect in-memory actions on mmap-ed files, and mmap is often used for file copying. So entire steps 2 and 3 might be missing.

You haven't specified target filesystem (and whether or not you expect to use inotify in uncontrolled environment), but beware, that some filesystems might not support inotify (FUSE-based and network filesystems tend to be especially problematic). This might depend on specific filesystem and kernel version in case of FUSE.

Creating hard links does not strictly qualify as copy, but it might result in post-mortem patterns resembling that situation (two files with same size and same apparent contents), so your app should better be inode-aware.

---

Because of reasons above, identifying copies with inotify is too much of chore, unless you expect significant payback. You should consider starting with identifying copies, using static analysis (because you will sometimes have fall back to it with inotify anyway).

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is very helpful.